# JQuery getJSON with getJSON not working

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I have code which creates a div type table which then populates certain data.  Within the set, I need to create a drop-down select which is populated from a second data set, set by the current JSON data.  But, and I have no idea why, the `<select>` just isn't showing - even when I dump the html output to the console, it's not there.  I've confirmed that the dataset contains information and it is valid JSON data, but it just doesn't work!

Here is my entire code block:

```
function GetData() {
    if ($('#orderno').val().length > 0) {   
        $('#results').html('<img src="../../../images/loading.gif" style="margin:90px auto auto auto; display:block;" />')
        $.getJSON("getdata.asp?orderno="+$('#orderno').val(), function(data){
            var len = data.length;  
            if (len == 0) {
                alert("None")
            } else {
                html = ' <div class="div-table"><div class="div-table-row">'
                html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td1">Sales Order</div>'
                html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td2">Part #</div><div class="div-table-col td3">Part Desc</div>'
                html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td4">Desp. Date</div><div class="div-table-col td5">Num.</div>'
                html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td6">Loc</div>'
                html = html + '</div></div>'
                for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
                    html = html + '<div class="div-table-row" val="'+data[i].salesorder+'">'
                    html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td1">'+data[i].salesorder+'</div>' 
                    html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td2">'+data[i].productcode+'</div>'    
                    html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td3">'+data[i].stockdesc+'</div>'  
                    html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td4">'+data[i].reqdate+'</div>'    
                    html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td5"><input id="despnum" type="number" min="0" max="'+data[i].qty+'" value="'+data[i].qty+'" disabled /></div>'
                    $.getJSON("getloc.asp?part="+data[i].productcode, function(data){
                        html = html + '<div class="div-table-col td6"><select id="location">'
                        var len2 = data.length;
                        for (var j = 0; j< len2; j++) {
                            console.log(data[j].binno)
                            html = html + '<option value="'+data[j].binno+'" >'+data[j].binno+'</option>'
                        }
                        html = html + '</select>'                       
                    })                  
                    html = html + '</div>'
                }
                html = html + '</div>'              
                $('#results').html(html);
            }           
        }); 
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In your developer tools, is the console showing any errors ?

Comment: None at all, just showing the data[j].binno values to confirm it is actually getting data

Comment: Can you console.log(html); just above $('#results').html(html); and post the response here

Comment: Oddly I did do that earlier on, but was a little surprised that it didn't create the `<select>` either.... 
`<div class="div-table-row" val="T50856-1/44"><div class="div-table-col td1">T50856-1/44</div><div class="div-table-col td2">LS/CMLRYG-E/ACL</div><div class="div-table-col td3">LS CML RYG- E DBLE CUT</div><div class="div-table-col td4">21/12/2015</div><div class="div-table-col td5"><input id="despnum" type="number" min="0" max="1" value="1" disabled /></div></div></div>` -- that is the final row being created (can't fit it all on due to character restrictions) - the <select> isn't there

Comment: Are you sure $.getJSON("getloc.asp?part="+data[i].productcode, function(data){ console.log(data); }) works as expected ? and returns the expected result

Comment: It is logging to console and I'm happy with the output (originally one didn't have any results but added in code to show none in JSON results so at least it returns something (and usually returns more than one per line).  But even if it didn't work right, it should start forming the `<select>`?